# scalar function in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use a function to strip anything but numeric characters from a column in a select statement. I'm getting the error that the multi-part identifier could not be bound on the line calling the function.

Here is my function

```
    create function scrubNetWt (@input varchar(50))
    returns varchar(50)
    AS
    Begin
        Return Left(
             SubString(@input, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @input), 8000), 
             PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(@input, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @input), 8000) + 'X')-1)
    End
```

Here is my select statement where I'm trying to use the function

```
    USE [TFP]
    GO

    SELECT [pick_ticket_id]
          ,[pick_ticket_no]
          ,[proform_net_wt] 
          ,[proform_cr_no]
          ,[TFP].[dbo].[scrubNetWt(proform_net_wt)] AS net_wt
    FROM [TFP].[dbo].[pick_ticket_ud]
```

Comment: Move the misplaced bracket: `[TFP].[dbo].[scrubNetWt](proform_net_wt)`.

Comment: personally I'd get rid of all the square brackets there. they arent needed for any of your object or column names

Comment: Ha! thank you very much. yep. it works. would you believe I just wasted an hour on this.

Comment: is this your completed function? It doesnt do what you describe. it looks like it extracts a single section of digits.

Comment: it is working. I wanted it to extract a single section of digits because there are a few instances where users have entered values for this column that look like this "1.14 KG / 2.50" when all it really needs is 1.14. No idea where the 2.50 came from. I did just run it on my data and it is returning the value I need for the report

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[TFP].[dbo].[scrubNetWt] (proform_net_wt)
```